# It is possible to refresh ViewBag value in the view?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm trying to do a dynamic dropdownlist :
I get the options of the dropdownlist from a database and put them in an objects list. In accordance with a checkbox value i remove objects from the list and set this list as a ViewBag value.

```
public ActionResult ThematicManagement(string Id, string IsAdult, string flagAdult)
             {
                .....
                ViewBag.DDL = null;      

                var response = VodCatalogBUS.GetParentThematics(); 
                List<oboThematic> list = new List<oboThematic>();
                list = response.Data;
                if (IsAdult == null || IsAdult == "false")            
                    list.RemoveAll(x => x.IsAdult == true && x.Id != 1007);           
                else 
                    list.RemoveAll(x => x.IsAdult == false && x.Id != 1007);                

                ViewBag.DDL = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name");
                ....
```

Then in my view i fill the dropdownlist like that :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ParentThematic", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDL, new { @class="dropdown" })    

<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="ChkIsAdult" name="ChkIsAdult">Adulte</label>
```

There is no problems here, i obtain the dropdown list with 4 options after the RemoveAll in the controller. Then if i click the checkbox, i must obtain 3 other options.

So I use an ajax call to return into the controller in the aim to update Viewbag's value :

```
 $('#ChkIsAdult').change(function () {                 
                var IsAdult = $('#ChkIsAdult').is(':checked');
                var url = dev + "/Legacy/ThematicManagement";
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {                        
                        IsAdult: IsAdult,
                        flagAdult : 'true',
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert('test');
                    }
                });               
            })
```

It works i return into the controller, but i think that the view isn't refresh so i retreive the old values (the 4 options) of the dropdownlist after clicking the checkbox.

I also try with ViewData and TempData to replace ViewBag but i've always the same proprem !

According to you, it is the good solution ? Can it works ?

Comment: Your ajax function only calls the controller method. It does not do anything with the returned value (what ever that is - but best guess it it would not work anyway). You need to call a separate method that returns json containing the data for the options and then update the DOM. However it might be better to include all options and then just show/hide options based on the value of the checkbox

Comment: I agree with you for show/hide options based on the checkbox value, i need to add one parameter in the select list, but i have one option which is in the two states of the checbkox how to differenciate it ?

Comment: Yes, That's why I indicated _might be better_  :) I didn't  know if there might be any logic you can apply to differentiate them

Comment: Finally i use this solution with using two dropdownlist hiding the one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the response :

Controller

```
 var response = VodCatalogBUS.GetParentThematics(); 
        List<oboThematic> list = new List<oboThematic>();

        list = response.Data;

            list.RemoveAll(x => x.IsAdult == true && x.Id != 1007);

            var responseAdult = VodCatalogBUS.GetParentThematics(); 
            List<oboThematic> listAdult = new List<oboThematic>();
            listAdult = responseAdult.Data;
            listAdult.RemoveAll(y => y.IsAdult == false && y.Id != 1007);                

        ViewBag.DDL = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.DDLAdult = new SelectList(listAdult, "Id", "Name");
```

View :

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ParentThematic", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDL, new { @class="dropdown" })
@Html.DropDownList("ParentThematicAdult", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLAdult, new { @class="dropdown" , @style="display:none"})
```

JS :

```
$('#ChkIsAdult').change(function () {                 
                if ($('#ChkIsAdult').is(':checked')) {
                    $('#ParentThematic').hide();
                    $('#ParentThematicAdult').show();
                    var value = $('#ParentThematicAdult').val();
                    var IsAdult = $('#ChkIsAdult').is(':checked');
                    var url = dev + "/Legacy/ThematicManagement";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            Id: value,
                            IsAdult: IsAdult
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#result').empty().append($(data).find('table'))
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    $('#ParentThematic').show();
                    $('#ParentThematicAdult').hide();
                    var value = $('#ParentThematic').val();
                    var IsAdult = $('#ChkIsAdult').is(':checked');
                    var url = dev + "/Legacy/ThematicManagement";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            Id: value,
                            IsAdult: IsAdult
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#result').empty().append($(data).find('table'))
                        }
                    });
                }                            
            })
```