# How to refresh the ViewBag?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I want to send either a **1** (New Code) or **0** (no New Code), but still the ViewBag only accepts the first value that is written to it.

**Controller**

```
        int timesRun = 0;
        int newID;
        private ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        [HttpGet]

        public IActionResult StartPage(string Code)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + Code);

            //Select BauTeilId
            var list = (from t in Context.Result select new { t.BauTeilId }).ToList();

            //Checking if already exists

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {

                if (Code != null)
                {
                    if (list[i].BauTeilId.Equals(Code))
                    {
                        newID = 0;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Keine neue ID " + newID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newID = 1;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Neue ID " + newID);
                        break;
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(list[i].BauTeilId);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.newID = newID;
            return View();
        }
```

---

**HTML**

```html
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Starter</title>

    <style>
        p {
            margin-top: 30%;
            margin-left: 20%;
            margin-right: 20%;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #Code {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example Code: 249765876358312345655</h1>


    <p>
        Eingabe des Maschinen Codes:
        <br />
        <input id="Code"
               name="Code"
               pattern=""
               size="30"
               spellcheck="false"
               title="Maschine Code"
               value="">
    </p>

    @{
        var data = ViewBag.newID;
        if(data != null)
        {
            data = ViewBag.newID.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }

    <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("Code");
            x.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
                //Getting the regex sorted out
            x = document.getElementById("Code").value;
            let vars = x;
            let digits = vars.match(/^\d{13}(\d{6})\d{2}$/)[1];
            let stringDigits = digits.toString();

            if (stringDigits.length == 6 && vars.length == 21) {

                //New ID or not
                let newID = '@data'.toString().toLowerCase();
                Boolean(newID);
                alert(newID);
                if (newID === '1') window.location.href = '/home/NewIDSettingsPage';
                else if(newID === '0')window.location.href = '/home/Kontrolle';
                else alert("ERROR");

                //Send to Kontrolle
                document.getElementById("Code").innerHTML = "";
                localStorage.setItem("Code_Kurz", stringDigits);
                localStorage.setItem("Code_Lang", x);

                //Send Code to Controller
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("StartPage")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {Code: stringDigits},
                   success: function (data) { console.log("Succ: " + data); },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                       var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                       console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);},
                });}});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to fix that or if there is an other solution to this.

Similar questions:
[How To Change or refresh data using ViewBag in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600307/how-to-change-or-refresh-data-using-viewbag-in-mvc3)
(That tutorial didnt help me either)

Comment: Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647342/it-is-possible-to-refresh-viewbag-value-in-the-view)
It's about the same topic. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume your list contains 2 rows and during for iteration first time this `if (list[i].BauTeilId.Equals(Code))` condition returns true and second time return false.

Your loop will set newID value based on last iteration. In last iteration if `if (list[i].BauTeilId.Equals(Code))` return 0 else 1.

Check out below updated code :

```
    if (Code != null)
    {
        if count > 0 will return 0 else return 1
        if (list.Where(x => x.BauTeilId.Equals(Code)).Count() > 0)
        {

            newID = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("Keine neue ID " + newID);
        }
        else
        {
            newID = 1;
            Debug.WriteLine("Neue ID " + newID);

         }

    }
    //pass value in viewbag
    ViewBag.newID = newID;
```

Comment: what is difference between his code and your code ?

Comment: Exactly He described the Code perfectly.

Comment: But I want to know how to fix it xD

Comment: @Klausk now u understood the issue apply your logic.

Comment: Whenever I type a new "Code" in the HTML Page it should then check if the database is has this Code already in it. If yes then it should go to this page(Kontrolle). If No it should go to that page(NewIDSettings).